# Sculpting tool will not manipulate sides of the model

Tags: sculpting

I made my mesh and was able to sculpt just fine on my model before. [image: sculpt tool worked on sides previously]  I felt the base mesh had some things I wanted to go back and change but of course the mirror was applied so I deleted the sculpt, deleted half of the base mesh. Made changes to the base mesh, mirrored, applied it.  When I tried to sculpt it again the brush stops short of some arbitrary wall on the side of the rib cage, if I try to model on the sides I get no results on the torso  yet the sculpt jumps to the hand instead, I've tried hiding one hand but then I see the other hand gets affected so I tried hiding both, still no results on the side of the torso.  I've tried masking the hands and even though I'm masking in the front and back view which is far from the lower torso the mask jumps to the lower torso instead of staying on the hand. I have tried recalculating normals,  I didn't have a problem with scale or rotation but I redid those anyway.  Nothing seems to work.
[image: sculpt tool fails to reach sides of model].